# Function that replaces the content of an element is saying that my element is null

Tags: javascript, html

I have a function where i create a new element in a div ("father-div") and append it to a textNode (which contains the content of the element). This does its objective.

```
function createElement(){
    var son = document.createElement("p");
    var node = document.createTextNode("some random text");
    son.appendChild(node);
    var father = document.getElementById("father-div");
    father.appendChild(son);
    son.id = "son-id";
}
```

I later want to change that text (i want it to be ' '), so i made this function which receives the id of the element i want to change (example: the previous "son-id" that i created). However i get this error: "Cannot read property 'replaceChild' of null".

```
function changeContent(elementId){ //examplo elementId="son-id"
    var newText = document.createTextNode('');
    var newChild = document.getElementById(elementId);
    newChild.replaceChild(newText, newChild);
}
```

How can i get it to do what i want and why doesn't this recognise the elementId?

inb4 "Use innerHTML", i can't use it for this task.

Comment: Yes, the parameters for `replaceChild` are incorrect because `newChild` _can't be a child of itself_ ( [see documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/replaceChild)), but the error message generated for that is about  "the node to be replaced is not a child of this node". The error message in the post is being generated by something else that has gone wrong but not shown in the post - can you make a code snippet to demonstrate how to reproduce it?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to run replace the element itself with a text node, that is not going to work. You should really use innerText;

```
function changeContent(elementId){ //examplo elementId="son-id"
    let element = document.getElementById(elementId);
    if(element){
        element.innerText = "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You use wrong syntax

To replace text node (first one in this case) use item.childNodes[0]

where item is "son" element

```
function changeContent(elementId){
      var newText = document.createTextNode(' '),
          item = document.getElementById(elementId);
      item.replaceChild(newText, item.childNodes[0]);
}
```

I also suggest to upgrade this function and add 2nd argument

```
function changeContent(elementId, content){
      var newText = document.createTextNode(content),
          item = document.getElementById(elementId);
      item.replaceChild(newText, item.childNodes[0]);
}
```

Comment: using indexing on the child nodes may not always yield predictable results, you have to be sure you really want to replace the 0th element.

Comment: I think the question was only regarding the first one `var son = document.createElement("p");
    var node = document.createTextNode("some random text");
    son.appendChild(node);`. Yes, it's better to use .innerHTML

Comment: the original poster should also consider wrapping the text nodes in span elements, and giving each element an id, that way they can be individually addressed and dealt with in a predictable fashion. If the poster only needs to wipe out all text in the element, then innerText should be used.